# Swift 3 nested dictionary extra brackets

Tags: swift

I am used to the brackets representing an array in swift. My question is what does the double brackets represent ? Below I give an example.

```
[[String : Any]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an array of dictionaries.

Use it like this:

```
theArray[0]["key"]
```